# Responsive Circle (javascript,html5,css)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm having a trouble on having a responsive circle
heres my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>


<button onclick = "myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script>
function myFunction(){
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
}
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

What i want to achieve here is that when i click the button it will produce a circle and it works now if click again the button it will produce another circle but it will automatically move from the other side like this example

```
first click: O

second click: O O

third click : O O

              O

fourth click: O O

              O O
```

like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use two variables posX and posY for x and y position for each circle

```
ctx.arc(posX, posY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
```

Here's an example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="550" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>


<button onclick = "myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script>
var posX = 100;
var posY = 75;
function myFunction(){
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(posX, posY, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
posX = posX + 120;
if(posX > 300)
{
  posY = posY + 120;
  posX = 100;
}
}
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why i did not think of it . genius . Thank you :)